# Apple Pay missing Entitlement warning

Tags: ios, entitlements, applepay

Have you ever received an email from Apple after submission like this?
The strangest thing is that I'm not using Apple Pay at all. Where should I look?

```
Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for “<APP>". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

Missing Entitlement - App contains references to [Apple Pay] in ‘ <BundleName>', but is missing the required entitlement 'com.apple.developer.in-app-payments'.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Regards,

The App Store team
```

**UPDATE:** See jrg answer (in my case fixed my issue) I had an outdated Braintree Cocoapod. Thanks man!

Comment: Are you using any links that bring people to apple pay or stores that use apple pay?

Comment: Sometimes the external libraries you use include those things in case you want to use it in the future. We got a similar message but about Push Notification when we included Mix Panel (analytics platform) into our app. Mix Panel has push notification but you don't have to use it.

Comment: It's about both things, it clearly mentioned Apple Pay in the email... how can that be off-topic?

BTW, thanks a lot to NewEngland and Zhang. I'm using Braintree SDK (Payments service), so I'm almost 100% that's the reason why this happened :-)

Comment: @betzerra, I m facing same issue , I m using lifepics sdk in my app, perhaps it could be root.Can u tell me how can I resolve this...???

Comment: I wish there was a response to this :((

Comment: If you're using an older version of the Braintree CocoaPod, then you'll get this issue. Braintree eventually separated out the ApplePay code into the Braintree/Apple-Pay pod. Other payment providers' SDKs may still be including the 'in-app payment' framework.